# Is gaining Fly as a class skill with the Feather Subdomain supposed to replace gaining Knowledge (Nature) with the Animal Domain?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, skills, cleric

I'm creating a cleric of Erastil and I'm thinking about choosing the Good domain and Feather subdomain. Should the Fly skill be the only class skill gained or is it supposed to supplement the Knowledge (Nature) class skill gained from the associated Animal domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get both.

the convention is that you get everything from the super-domain **except** for the features the sub-domain **explicitly** says get replaced.

I couldn't find any great sources to cite. This is the closest I could find:

> Each subdomain replaces a granted power and a number of spells in the
>   domain’s granted spell list.

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains

It makes sense to give fly in addition to Knowledge(Nature) because you still get Animal domain powers/spells but the fly skill is also needed because you now have access to the fly spell.

Comment: The quoted rule certainly *sounds* like a subdomain replaces the entire granted power (e.g. adding Knowledge (nature) to the Cleric class skill list), so you would not get both...

Comment: Granted powers and knowledge skills are different. I read that as implying that the subdomain ONLY replaces the granted power and number of spells.

Comment: With the feather sub-domain you still get the Animal companion feature from the Animal domain. Something I think would be odd to have if you didn't also have access to knowledge(Nature) as a class skill. Class archetypes also follow a similar convention where they only remove features that are explicitly mentioned as replaced, however they specifically mention this in that section of the rules.

Comment: @IgneusJotunn [Animal Domain](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/animal-domain) certainly lists adding Knowledge (nature) as part of its Granted Power. Oddly, the Feather Subdomain lists Fly separately from its "Replacement Granted Power." I think this is the point where I shake my head at the absurdity of Paizo still having these kinds of ambiguities in their game.